# SEO friendly ModRewrite + data structure

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently in the process of making my URL schemes much more SEO and user friendly.

I have an index page which passes a variable to a video page, which then loads the corresponding item from my MySQL db. In the database I have fields like so:

```
ID (Key Value)   Name            Title
---------------  --------------  ---------------
1                Client          Video One
```

At present my URL's are fetched as:

http://example.com/video.php?=20

Through a bit of ModRewrite experimentation I have the much better

http://example.com/video/20/

However, what I'd really like is to have the following:

http://example.com/video/client/

I'm aware that `.htaccess` can't access my database so can't automatically switch the `ID` for the `Name` value.

My thinking is instead of using the key value (ID in this case) I could simply use the 'Name' field. However I have a few concerns doing this:

- if my `Name` data has spaces in the database entry (as some do - for example `client one`) how will this affect things?
- Also, some 'Name' entries may contain duplicates by having more than one piece of work assigned to them (again, `Client One` might have `Client One - Video One` `Client One - Video Two` etc.)

What's the best way of fetching the data and using ModRewrite to achieve a solution?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to replace space to [_,-,+] then get the NAME of video by ID form database in PHP. try it

i know its not a best answer for you... it just for suggestion.